# User does not have permissions to directory

Tags: usb, permissions

My raspberry 3 is running amule using amule user, but I cant set the directories I want for incomings and temp files in a pendrive. Each time it goes back to the default directories.

I did `sudo chmod 777` for both folder but didnt work.

This is the log:

```
2020-01-26 00:27:24: Initialising aMuleD 2.3.2 compiled with wxBase(GTK2) v3.0.4 and Boost 1.67
 2020-01-26 00:27:24: Checking if there is an instance already running...
 2020-01-26 00:27:24: No other instances are running.
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: ERROR: Error accessing directory. Permissions on the temp directory too strict!
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: aMule cannot proceed. To fix this, you must set read/write/exec
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: permissions for the folder '/media/usb/downloads/temp'
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: Attempting to use default directory at location 
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: '/home/amule/.aMule/Temp'.
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: ERROR: Error accessing directory. Permissions on the incoming directory too strict!
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: aMule cannot proceed. To fix this, you must set read/write/exec
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: permissions for the folder '/media/usb/downloads/'
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: Attempting to use default directory at location 
!2020-01-26 00:27:24: '/home/amule/.aMule/Incoming'.
 2020-01-26 00:27:24: Creditfile loaded, 5 clients are known
```

How can I grant read/write/exec permissions to amule user?

Comment: `chmod` to set permissions, `chown` to change ownership - it's up to you which you'll need to use - however if `/media/usb` is an external HD device using a DOS filesystem (fat, ntfs), then you'll struggle with chmod/chown ... you'll perhaps need to add amule user to a group that has relevant permissions for external devices

Comment: If it is a FAT filesystem, the trick may be to set the owner, group, and permissions in the mount options.  NTFS may be similar, or not.  In ant case, check `man mount`.